# Doctor Robotnik (Erlang) commands and variables

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I am using the code from:

https://github.com/kivra/robotnik

And am unable to get the engine to start scraping. I suspect it is because I am unfamiliar with the commands needed to start the engine.

Once compiled, the command "`robot_example:init("search").`" returns a response "`{ok,[search,browse],[]}`".

Similarly, "`robot_example:kill().`" will return an "`{ok}`".

Now, I am aware I need two arguments for the "`robot_example:attack`" of which the first one is "search" or "browse" as the case may have you, I believe. What I am unsure of is the argument needed for the variable "_State" in order to get the engine underway and processing.

Any pointers most welcome!

Comment: What exactly is the return value of the call to `robot_example:init/1`? What you have written is not legal erlang.

Comment: I went further in the code, and it seems that it is not finish yet. The main supervisor does not start any process, there is a typo in the example (robotnik:payload_encode instead of robotnik:encode_payload), the gen_robot behaviour implements only the behaviour_info(callbacks) ...

Answer (score 1):

For both methods, the second parameter is the current state of the robot. The search method (in the example) ignore this first parameter, so I guess that you should start by this one:

```
{next,State1} = robot_example:attack(search,[]).
```

then you should be able to do

```
{ok,IP_addr} = robot_example:attack(browse,State1).
```

(I didn't test it, just read the code, so I can't guarantee that it works...).